# Correct way to use PtrUseVisitor Class in LLVM

Tags: c++, inheritance, llvm, parent-child, llvm-c++-api

So I found the `InstVisitor` class in LLVM, which was refreshing to traverse through the function and see instructions of my interest. A straightforward implementation that I was able to get it working is as follows:

```
class MyInstVisitor : public InstVisitor <MyInstVisitor> {
    public:

    void visitLoadInst(Instruction &I) {
        errs() << "Load:\t" << I << "\n";
    }
};
```

Afterward, the usage case is as follows:

```
void visitor(Function &F) {
    MyInstVisitor MAV;
    MAV.visit(F);
    for (auto &I : F) {
        errs() << I << "\n"; // this traverses a function through for loop
    }
}
```

After looking around further, I found a child class of `InstVisitor`, a `PtrUseVisitor` (https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PtrUseVisitor.html) that I wanted to use (as I wish to visit all of the users of a pointer value after locating the `llvm::LoadInst`).

However, I am stuck trying to find a way to use this correctly.

I have tried a variety of things, to summarize:

1. `PtrUseVisitor` cannot be instantiated like `InstVisitor`
2. as the template looks like this: `llvm::PtrUseVisitor<DerivedT>` I have also tried doing something like `llvm::PtrUseVisitor<Instruction>::visitPtr()`, which is incorrect.
3. I think I'm missing something regarding how to use the child class of inheritance, but examples I could find are related to elementary things (such as inheriting from class `Animal`, for instance)

And many more... just a bit lost at the moment.

My main goal is to use the following member function:
`PtrUseVisitor::visitPtr()`. Can anyone help with providing me with an example of how to use this?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [SROA](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/SROA.cpp) pass, which defines a class `AllocaSlices::SliceBuilder` which inherits from `PtrUseVisitor`. If you look in that class for calls to `Base::` methods, those are making using of `PtrUseVisitor`.